# How to use external static files with Django (serving external files once again)?

Tags: django, file, static

even after Googling and reading all relevant posts at StackOverflow, I still can't get static files working in my Django application.

I am using a development server, here is how my files look:

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static')
MEDIA_URL = '/static/'
```

**urs.py**

```
from DjangoBandCreatorSite.settings import DEBUG
if DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('', (
        r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$',
        'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': 'static'}
    ))
```

**template:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

I am trying to use jquery.js stored in directory "static".

This is the complete code of my template:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <style>

      span 
      {
        color: blue;
        text-decoration:underline;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      .nav{
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: large;
        color: cadetblue;
      }

    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {

       $.get("content.html", addContent);   // calls addContent() with argument "content.html"

       function addContent(data)            // fills <div id='content'> with what gets as an argument (in this template, it is "content.html")
       {
          $("#content").html(data);          
       }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="content">
  {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    <!--THE RETURN VALUE OF addContent() IS INSERTED HERE-->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I use src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"

instead of src="/static/jquery.js"

in the script tag,everything works fine. But when trying to use /static/jquery.js, I get a blank page when I open my application in a browser.

I am using:
Windows XP
Python 2.6.4
Django 1.2.3

Thank you very much for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't properly set document_root for static_serve view. Also note how settings should be imported.

```
from django.conf import settings

# ...

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^%s/(?P<path>.*)$'  % settings.MEDIA_URL.strip('/'),
            'django.views.static.serve',
            {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
             'show_indexes': True}),
    )
```

This should work for Django 1.2, there are some differences in 1.3. If this does not help, try add some asserts to your settings:

```
assert MEDIA_ROOT == r'your/path/here'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. Thank you for advice about importing settings.

Comment: Check debug page that Django shows to you or share it somewhere.

Comment: If I open my application in a browser, I don't get a debug page, but I get a blank page :-( I edited the question to provide more info.

Comment: So, in settings.py: MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static')   MEDIA_URL = '/static/'   and in template: <script src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}jquery.js"></script>   ? I still get a blank page.

Comment: You should get Django debug page if you have DEBUG = True in settings and 404 Not Found page if not.

Comment: I have DEBUG = True, but no debug page appears.

Comment: I can only assume that you are loading/editing wrong settings.py file. First try to get debug page working.

Comment: If I add a print statement to my settings.py, it is printed out, so I am loading/editing the right settings.py file. Can there be something else that I am missing to get debug page working other than DEBUG=True ?

Comment: Problem solved. In urls.py I used urlpatterns = patterns('views',.......    (r'^.*$', 'index'),        Instead, it needed to be urlpatterns = patterns('',.......    (r'^.*$', 'views.index'), thank you very much for your time and patience.